# Pass multiple strings to the string::find function

Tags: c++, string, find

Is it possible to somehow pass multiple strings to the string::find function?

For example, to find a string I might use this:

```
str.find("a string");
```

What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
str.find("a string" || "another string" || "yet another string")
```

And have the function return the position of the first occurrence of any of the three strings.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The generalized method of finding strings is known as `regex` and it's a part of standard C++. The REGular EXpression here is `(a )|((yet )?another) string`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not with `std::string::find`, but you could use [std::find_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) from `<algorithm>`:

```
std::string str("a string");
std::array<std::string, 3> a{"a string", "another string", "yet another string"};
auto it = std::find_if(begin(a), end(a),
                       [&](const std::string& s)
                       {return str.find(s) != std::string::npos; });
if (it != end(a))
{
    std::cout << "found";
}
```

Comment: http://cpp.sh/2qgso
doesn't seem to work for single chars or?
what is the &s reference?

Comment: http://cpp.sh/6hbpr another test: searching for string.
i'm looking for a mechanism that looks if for example "i" (in this case) occurs in al strings.

Answer (score 3):

That is not possible but what you can do is:

```
auto is_there(std::string haystack, std::vector<std::string> needles) -> std::string::size_type {

  for(auto needle : needles ){
    auto pos = haystack.find(needle);
    if(pos != std::string::npos){
      return pos;
    }

  }  
  return std::string::npos;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either call `find` multiple times or construct a regular expression from the strings that you want to find. C++11 has support for regular expressions in [`<regex>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it is present with the following code

```
bool is = string("AB|CD|EF").find("AB") != string::npos ;
```