# Find specific text in string delimited by newline characters

Tags: c++, string

I want to find a specific string in a list of sentence. Each sentence is a line delimited with a `\n`. When the newline is reached the current search should stop and start new on the next line.

My program is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    string filename;
    string list = "hello.txt\n abc.txt\n check.txt\n"
    cin >> filename;
    // suppose i run programs 2 times and at 1st time i enter abc.txt
    // and at 2nd time i enter abc
    if(list.find(filename) != std::string::npos){
       //I want this condition to be true only when user enters complete
       // file name. This condition also becoming true even for 'abc' or 'ab' or even for 'a' also

        cout << file<< "exist in list";
    }
    else cout<< "file does not exist in list"
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way around. i want to find only filenames in the list

Comment: Use a `std::regex` may be.

Comment: This is exact duplicate of ["(C++) Pass multiple strings to the string::find function"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19952155/c-pass-multiple-strings-to-the-stringfind-function)

Comment: I'm having a weird sense that you only want the condition to be true if it matches the whole line, i.e. till `\n`. Tell me if i'm wrong.

Comment: yes Muhammad Ahmad it is like that.

Comment: And you have to have only one string which contains all these file names? Not a vector or something?

Comment: yes i have only one string which has this list of file names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I wouldn't keep the list of files in a single string, but I would use any sort of list or vector. 
Then if keeping the list in a string is a necessity of yours (for some kind of reason in your application logic) I would separate the string in a vector, then cycle through the elements of the vector checking if the element is exactly the one searched.
To split the elements I would do:

```
std::vector<std::string> split_string(const std::string& str,
                                  const std::string& delimiter)
{
    std::vector<std::string> strings;

    std::string::size_type pos = 0;
    std::string::size_type prev = 0;
    while ((pos = str.find(delimiter, prev)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        strings.push_back(str.substr(prev, pos - prev));
        prev = pos + 1;
    }

    // To get the last substring (or only, if delimiter is not found)
    strings.push_back(str.substr(prev));

    return strings;
}
```

You can see an example of the function working [here](http://ideone.com/UHWNQW)

Then just use the function and change your code to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
string filename;
string list = "hello.txt\n abc.txt\n check.txt\n"
cin >> filename;

vector<string> fileList = split_string(list, "\n");
bool found = false;
for(int i = 0; i<fileList.size(); i++){
    if(fileList.at(i) == file){
        found = true;
    }
}
if(found){
    cout << file << "exist in list";
} else {
    cout << "file does not exist in list";
}
return 0;
}
```

Obviously you need to declare and implement the function `split_string` somewhere in your code. Possibly before `main` declaration.

Comment: Why not setting up a `std::vector<std::string>` in 1st place?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes of course. I thought the list as a string was a necessity of the guy who asked the question. If this isn't the case well yes you are right. I'll edit the question to make it clear

Answer (score 2):

`list.find` will only find substring in the string `list`, but if you want to compare the whole string till you find the `\n`, you can tokenize the `list` and put in some vector.

For that, you can put the string `list` in `std::istringstream` and make a `std::vector<std::string>` out of it by using `std::getline` like:

```
std::istringstream ss(list);
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

std::string temp;
while (std::getline(ss, temp)){
    tokens.emplace_back(temp);
}
```

If there are leading or trailing spaces in the tokens, you can trim the tokens before adding them to the vector. For trimming, see [What's the best way to trim std::string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216823/whats-the-best-way-to-trim-stdstring), find a trimming solution from there that suits you.

And after that, you can use `find` from `<algorithm>` to check for complete string in that vector.

```
if (std::find(tokens.begin(), tokens.end(), filename) != tokens.end())
    std::cout << "found" << std::endl;
```